# Product of two ideals in polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

It is easy I want to make sure if got the idea right

Assume $R=Z[x,y]$, $I=<xy,y^2>$, $J=<x^2,xy>$ are two ideals of $R$ then

$ I J=<x^3 y,x^2 y^2,x^2 y^2, x y^3>$. Is it right?

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: It's correct; however, as a final answer, you should delete the repeated generator $x^2y^2$.

Comment: @Team I delete **i**. is this correct?